# Am I allowed not to fast if I slept in and didn't make niyyah (itention)?

Tags: sawm, ramadan

I was tired yesterday, and I couldn't help I just slept before even the sunset.  Next thing I know I woke after like an hour after fajr time, I had slept for nearly 12 hours.

Now I haven't taken suhoor I haven't even made my niyyah, and I feel so dizzy because I haven't eaten for more than 15 hours and now I have to fast for maybe another 15 hours.

And I don't know if I'm allowed to not fast today, and then fast it back after Ramadan, because I didn't do my niyyah.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is **no** you are not allowed not to fast.

Most scholars (Maliki, Shafi'i, Hanbali, see also [this fatwa](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/290641)) say that one should do the niyyah (for Ramadan fasting) during the night (before fajr), but in cases like yours, you have missed the time to make the niyyah you are asked to do it once you wake up this is a correct qiyas to the similar case of the person who missed prayers -because he/she [was sleeping](https://sunnah.com/muslim:684c)- and has to perform them once he/she remembers them. So this is an allowed exception for the "rule".

On the other hand note that:

> قال شيخ الإسلام كما في الاختيارات: ومن خطر بقلبه أنه صائم غداً فقد نوى
>
> Ibn Taymiyyah said: If you had in mind that you are fasting tommorrow then you already have made your niyyah.

So the niyyah matter is easy.

---

**Note** this rule -of making niyyah at night- applies for Ramadan fasting kafara fasting and for those who have to fast missed days of Ramadan. For optional fasts most scholars say performing niyyah before fajr isn't necessary you could even wake up in the day in decide to fast, as the Messenger of Allah (Peace be upon him) [used to do](http://sunnah.com/muslim/13/221).

But if you made suhoor a condition for fasting (and it was not an obligatory fasting) than you could still not fast.

---

If you didn't fast intentionally because you didn't make niyyah and suhoor in an obligatory fast like Ramadan, then you may have to do a kafara feeding 60 poor people or fasting two  successive lunar months. Because you committed a sin.
You are only allowed not to complete (an obligatory) fasting once you feel that fasting this day would make you suffer or would harm you in that case you only need to make up this day without any kafara as stated for the sick in ([2:184](http://legacy.quran.com/2/184)). For example if you felt terribly hungry and/or thirsty and felt you couldn't complete your day fasting. As Allah says:

> ...  and do not throw [yourselves] with your [own] hands into destruction...([2:195](http://legacy.quran.com/2/195))

and

> ...  And do not kill yourselves [or one another]. Indeed, Allah is to you ever Merciful. ([4:29](http://legacy.quran.com/4/29))

Here some references in Arabic:
About the [niyyah](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/277978).
[Fasting](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/303823) if you missed iftar and suhoor.

If you can read Arabic I also strongly suggest you to read the answers on the questions 39, 45 and 47 on [this site](https://saaid.net/mktarat/ramadan/137.htm).

See also [this Fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/207728) on the niyyah in English.

Comment: ASA, I fasted yesterday and i am already fasting for today, However I am diabetic and these long fasts whilst possible are likely to become harder over time, I have been told that if I am unable to fast i have 2 options, 1) Pay Fidya for the missed fast, or 2) Redo the fast at a later date when i can do it. Is this correct as I will be choosing 2 if i have to miss any due to my lack of money to make the required payments (£100 for the month)

Comment: @TheresaForster First note that this is a new question, you'd better ask it separately on the site. 2nd AFAIK diabetic people shouldn't even fast and you might feed for each day, as fasting shouldn't be an option -personally i don't know anybody who who is diabetic whom a doctor allowed him to fast- and you don't need to pay the fidya at once so maybe you could do that step by step see for example https://islamqa.info/en/49944 which declares your 2nd option as void for your case. **Note** that in cases you are not able to pay maybe there's even an option that there's a favorable fatwa.

Comment: الكفارة من الإفطار بالجماع فقط.

Comment: Kafara (60 consicutive Days) is done only when the iftar was done by having sexual relationship with the wife or "Jimaa' " جماع. Otherwise he performs Kadaa  قضاء ، he fasts a replacment day.

Comment: @DrWael this might be shafi'i view see my post on http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32558/what-is-the-difference-between-qiyas-and-istislah-and-could-you-provide-examples/32567#32567 others regard intentionally eating on a day of Ramadan without an excuse as a major sin انتهاك حرمة الصيام.

Answer (score -3):

You're allowed not to fast.

1. As you said you havent' taken suhoor, now I don't know how climate treats you there, but generally it is very hot. So instead of fasting and getting unconscious in the middle of fast and create problems for others, it's better not to fast at all.
2. Namaz (Prayers) are more important than fasting, you should be more careful about your prayers.

ALLAH says in Qur'an (in context of Fast in Surah Baqarah), "ALLAH want ease for you, ALLAH does not want to create problems for you"