# Fast broken due to intercourse - ruling

Tags: ramadan, intercourse

Salam brothers and sisters.
My intention was to fast the night before and unfortunately the fast was broken due to my wife's desire. I was weak and had broken my fast. My Allah SWT forgive me.

This happened as I am travelling for business and staying in a hotel for the week on this business trip, and the wife (who is of the book, but not a Muslim) accompanied me.

I have repented and continue to repent. I also paid Kafaarah (feed 60 poor people). I am wondering what other ruling is there that I must follow to make up for this but also so Allah SWT can forgive me.

Thank you.

Comment: This [I had unintentional sex with my wife while fasting can i still proceed ...](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33223/i-had-unintentional-sex-with-my-wife-while-fasting-can-i-still-proceed-with-fas) should be related or maybe even answering your question as you didn't give enough details this is only my guess, else consider editing and elaborating your post.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure what else to add to the post?

Comment: In the case that you can't add anything to the post it would be a duplicate of the one linked by @Medi. Note that the majority of scholars say that kafarah has to be taken in order this means only if you can't fast 2 consecutive months you are allowed to feed 60 poor people.

Comment: The thing is, I did not know about this until AFTER I was researching and AFTER the fact.

Answer (score 1):

Since you paid your Kaffaarah, Allah Insha'allah will forgive you.
What you need to do now is repent to Allah that you will never do this mistake again, and he will accept you Insha'allah as he is the most-forgiving.

Comment: Do I also need to fast for 60 consecutive days after eid?

Comment: No brother. But you should know that next time if you break you fasting, you should fast 2 months as a kaffarah. Feeding 60 poor is an option to those who can't fast. However this time may Alllah forgive you because you did not know. The prophet said: "Allah has pardoned for my Ummah: what they did not know, their forgetfulness, and that which they have been forced to do."

Comment: Well, I knew that in proceeding I would break the fast and did not want to do that at all. That's all I knew at the time until I started to research and read about the punishment... and now I know the consequences. Would I still need to do 60 days?

Comment: If you know prior to your breaking that the Kafaraah is fasting 60 days, and that feeding 60 people is not available for you because you can fast, then you must fast the 60 days. We can not just pick the easiest kafaarah. We must do what we are ordered to do so that we do not rerurn to sins again. Kaffarah is purification, and you are a good brother for seeking forgivness. May allah grants you.

Comment: Thank you. No, I did NOT know that the penalty would be 60 days. I only found out AFTER researching and AFTER the invalidation of fast.

Comment: My understanding was if the fast is broken, you must repent but also make up for the day. I did not know that because of this act, the penalty would be 60 consecutive days.

Comment: then you are good to go. Just repent to Allah and never do this again. And may Allah grants you forgivness

Comment: I wonder how you could answer a question lacking information in which scholars have discussed at least 5 different cases!

Comment: Is my answer wrong?