# Ruling on intercourse with wife in ramadan while we were asleep and around 7:30am we had this situation while fasting

Tags: sawm, ramadan, intercourse

What is the ruling in islam in this situation?Ruling on intercourse with wife in ramadan while we were asleep and around 7:30am we had this situation while fasting

Comment: While asleep, by that means you didn't remember that you were fasting and in sleep you did, in that case, no worries, but as soon as you remember that you were fasting you should stop immediately or if you remembered that you were fasting then qaza and kaffara you both will have to be done. but again I am not a scholar get it clarified by a scholar

Comment: Isn't your inquiry covered in [I had unintentional sex with my wife while fasting...](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33223/i-had-unintentional-sex-with-my-wife-while-fasting-can-i-still-proceed-with-fas)?

Answer (score -1):

> Abu Hurayrah (radiyallāhu ‘anhu) narrated that a man came to Allah’s
> Messenger (salallāhu ‘alaihi wasallam) and said: “**I am destroyed O
> Messenger of Allah**!” Allah’s Messenger (salallāhu ‘alaihi wasallam)
> asked him: “**And what has destroyed you**?” He responded: “**I had sexual
> intercourse with my wife while fasting in Ramadan**.” The Messenger
> (salallāhu ‘alaihi wasallam) said: “**Are you able to free a slave?**” He
> replied: “**No**.” The Messenger (salallāhu ‘alaihi wasallam) said: “**Are
> you able to fast two months consequently**?” He said: “**No**.” The
> Messenger (salallāhu ‘alaihi wasallam) asked: “**Can you find food to
> feed sixty poor people?**” He replied: “**No**.” Then the man sat down.
>
> A little while later, the Messenger (salallāhu ‘alaihi wasallam) was
> given a large basket of dates. He turned to the man and said: “**Go and
> give this in charity**.” The man said: “**And is there anyone who is
> poorer than us? There is not a family living between the two lava
> plains of Madinah more in need of it than us**.” The Prophet (salallāhu
> ‘alaihi wasallam) laughed till his back teeth became visible. Then he
> said: “**Go and feed your family with it**.”

This hadīth proves that the kaffārah (expiation) is obligatory for sexual intercourse while fasting and it is:

1. Free a slave, and it must be a believing slave.
2. If he cannot find a believing slave to free, then he must fast for
   two months consecutively.
3. If he cannot do that, then he must feed sixty poor people half a sā’
   (1.2kg) each.

This hadīth also proves that if one is not able to pay the expiation at all, then the obligation is lifted because the Prophet (salallāhu ‘alaihi wasallam) did not command this man with anything further. However, some scholars hold that the Prophet (salallāhu ‘alaihi wasallam) paid the expiation on his behalf with a large basket of dates and that is why the obligation was lifted

Above Hadith reference: Ahmad (no. 7290), Bukhāri (no. 1936), Muslim (no. 1111)