# How do I make up for the prayers I have missed over the past few years?

Tags: fiqh, prayer-timings, salat-qada

Currently in my mid teens, I never used to pray regularly. I have now started to pray regularly, so how can I make up for the prayers I have missed?

Comment: My answer on https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31079/what-do-i-do-if-i-missed-joined-prayers/31080#31080 or https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25969/should-i-make-up-for-6-10-years-of-possibly-invalid-prayer-and-fasts/33551#33551  should cover your inquiry.

Answer (score 1):

Prophet Muhammad said:

> Whenever one of you misses a Salaah due to sleeping or due to negligence, it is obligatory upon him/her that he/she pray the Salaah when he remembers it because God has metioned, “Perform Salah when you remember me”(Muslim,Hadith 1569)

According to [*myislam.com*](http://www.myislaam.com/question/make-missed-salah/) you have to make up all the missed prayers because no one knows when the time of death will come, and you should make a clear intention to make up. But, you can simply seek His forgiveness and attend not to repeat again, and then start praying.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I'm 15 and reached puberty at around 12. So now I pray every Salah a second time. I will do this until I'm 18 since that will make up the 3 years I missed. After that, I'll go back to making 5 fardh salah every day instead of 10. This is working for me, just remember how long it took you to start praying regularly again. The gap should be the amount of time you continue to do this.

Comment: if you pray 10 salahs every day for 3 years, and get used to it, why stop? Keep praying 10 Salahs, the main 5, and let the other 5 be for the sake of getting closer to Allah. More Salah is better for you, in this life and the hereafter. Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him said: if the human sees hellfire, he'd pray until his back breaks. I'm sure if he sees heaven he'd also pray that much. Allah Hafiz